# Poweredge R710 configuring RAID 10 with one disk missing

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid10

I have ordered Poweredge R710 server with 4 diskas planning to configure them as RAID10. However I only got 3 disks delivered (4th will be delivered in 10 days).

I am wondering can I create RAID10 array with one disk missing and start installing my system (aware of possible risks in case the disk dies), and then when the disk arrives I just add it to the system? Will RAID BIOS let me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I'm afraid this is not possible.

Comment: You mean I have to have all physical disks in order to setup array. There is no possibility to mark disk "missing" when I create RAID configuration?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying.